# Physical Significance of Irreducible representation of 3D rotation group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

I read about the irreducible representation of groups in the book 'Lie Algebra in Particle Physics'. Since then, I have been wondering if there is a special physical meaning hidden in irreducible representation of groups arising in theoretical physics. I found an example in Sakurai's QM that the rotation matrices in the $L^2, L_z$ basis space are irreducible representation since rotation conserves $L^2$, however, I couldn't generalize this fact to get the deeper meaning.

On the other hand, an irreducible representation can be trivially constructed, we can have two sets and we define different representations on them, then we simply merge the sets and new representations are simply concatenation of older ones in one-to-one fashion by choice, then we can get an irreducible representation even though individual representations might not have been irreducible.

But if this is really trivial, then there would have not be so much emphasis on irreducible representations?

Comment: More on [irreps of the Poincare group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poincare-symmetry+representation-theory).

Comment: Deeper meaning? You did not follow the deadly triumphant applications in Sakurai's text you are referring to?